# How to print table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input, printing

Using below code i can able to print table, but i not able to print the  value which i was entered. any one can help.....

Here is the code.....

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function printDiv()
            {
              var divToPrint=document.getElementById('demo');
              newWin= window.open("");
              newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
              newWin.print();
              newWin.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="tundra">
        <div>
            <table   id="demo" >
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" ></td>
                    <td> cell 11    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" ></td>
                    <td> cell 12</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. Let us know EXACTLY what is going wrong, along with any attempts that you have made yourself.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrUbX/)***</kbd>
You can replace all inputs with there value and then can print the table... Doing it completely using javascript is pretty *difficult* but not *impossible*.

**jQuery**

```
function printDiv() {
    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        var cell = $(this);
        cell.replaceWith('<span>' + cell.val() + '</span>');
    });
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('demo');
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
divToPrint=document.getElementById('demo');
```

Will take the DOM input elements in the same way they where loaded at first time.
For example, if your input has

```
value="test"
```

in your html code, then it will be showed in the print.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not the table but the `input` elements. When the user enters data, it is stored in the `value` properties of `input` element nodes in the Document Object Model. But when you write the enclosing `div` element in another document, only the elements and their HTML attributes are written—the values are discarded.

The solution is to make the data part of the markup, by setting the `value` attribute according to the `value` property. For this, you can first clone the `div` element using the [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) method and then the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) method to get all `input` elements inside it. This means that you would replace the first statement inside the `printDiv` function by the following:

```
          var divToPrint=document.getElementById('demo').cloneNode(true);        
          var inputs = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('input');
          for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
            inputs[i].setAttribute('value', inputs[i].value);
```